# Mark non db fields @Transient vs extent JPA Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jcr

We have a `JPA Entity`. Once the entity is persisted in db, some fields of this entity(db columns) along with some other data (which is not part of this entity) has to be stored in a JCR object-store.

Should I create one single Entity(JPA) for both DB and JCR and just add JCR fields in Entity and mark them `@Transient?`

or

Should I use inheritance or composition(using JPA Entity) and create a new JCR specific object? Basically, should JPA entities be strictly used for DB or is `@Transient` in this case an abuse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> should JPA entities be strictly used for DB or is `@Transient` in this case an abuse?

Not an abuse but you will need to tread very carefully with JPA operations. One `merge` or `refresh` too many and your transient field value is lost.

Personally I'd create another layer of abstraction over both JPA and JCR that would manage your domain object as POJOs, some sort of `DomainObjectRepository` that would handle CRUD operations, interacting with *both* JPA and JCR, and encapsulating the mapping from/to both storage technologies (with mapping layer to each technology having a dedicated set of objects - JPA entities, JCR nodes).

Comment: Well said. The other thing to consider is that if you mix the two layers in the same object, then you run the possibility of using objects that have been only partially initialized / loaded (you loaded the entity via Hibernate and do not set the hibernate-transient values). This increases the likelihood that future development would introduce bugs caused by partially-initialized objects.

Comment: We decided to go with this approach, Thank you.