# Is it safe to assume that @Transient makes JPA provider to leave annotated field always intact?

Tags: java, jpa, transient

Motivated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62943216/6413377) I began to study more in details the functionality of JPA's `@Transient` annotation. In mentioned answer stands:

> One merge or refresh too many and your transient field value is lost.

Then every documentation I have had a glance says approximately the same:

> Fields annotated with @Transient are not persisted

I found nothing about ignoring such a field totally and I realize I have no explicit evidence but somehow I have always understood it implicitly like ***@Transient annotated fields are ignored by JPA (provider)***.

Would there be a point - for an example - to fetch such a field from the database if it is never persisted there, I mean persisted in a JPA context. For such there are @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false) I guess?

So could it really be that I should be aware that **merge** or **refresh** for an entity, managed or not at the time of operation, makes the value of some `@Transient` field change?

And if yes, what would be a simple example of such situation?

Comment: Merge or refresh are likely to change the value of any transient field to null. They can return a completely new entity based on the DB values ignoring transient attributes (as intended). I personally prefer to use transient only for caching values that can be recalculated if needed.

Comment: 'I have always understood it implicitly like @Transient annotated fields are ignored by JPA (provider)' - and that understanding is perfectly correct. *Ignored* as in 'let's pretend they don't exist' ignored. Which implies no special care is taken to preserve them, either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **I would like to consider 3 scenarios**

  - Calling `merge` on unmanaged entity where unmanaged entity is populated with a transient field
  - Calling `merge` on managed entity where managed entity is populated with a transient field after it became managed
  - Calling refresh on managed entity where managed entity is populated with a transient field after it became managed. It is not allowed to call `refresh` on a unmanaged entity anyway
- **Calling `merge` on unmanaged entity where unmanaged entity is populated with a transient field**.

  - Implementation is free to return a new entity and that means transient field is lost. I have verified the behaviour with hibernate and it loses the value. Even if some implementations make it not lose value, I wouldn't rely it as merge is free to return new entity.
- **Calling `merge` on managed entity where managed entity is populated with a transient field after it became managed**.

  - It is a managed entity so JPA need to provide `repeatable read`. So even if you perform `merge`, JPA has to satisfy both guarantees, i.e the object reference you have for the managed entity cannot change and that object should contain latest value from db. There is no reason for JPA to touch your transient field. It will just update any field that are managed and has been updated in the database since. I have verified this behaviour and behaves as expected.
- **Calling refresh on managed entity where managed entity is populated with a transient field after it became managed**.

  - Same argument as merging managed entity. JPa cannot lose your transient value. I have verified this behaviour and behaves as expected.

**Summary**

- You will lose the transient value of an unmanaged entity when you call merge.

**GitRepo**

- https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stackoverflow-63003677. Just import the spring boot project as a maven project and start the app. It will run above 3 scenarios and print the outcome to console

Comment: Great detailed answer. I'll have a deeper look later. Just wonder that what would be the benefit - or difficulty to not - to create a new entity instead of just using the one that is passed to merge in case _merge on unmanaged_ . Also if you happen to know any official documentation for this _Implementation is free to return a new entity_

Comment: @pirho, IMO  method signature `merge` api itself is the documentation. `session.merge(entity)` has a return value while `session.refresh(entity)` does not.  And note the word copy the object to persistent object. I.e if the object passed to merge is unmanaged, it stays unmanaged, hibernate won't touch it. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge(java.lang.Object). Most of the time, I am able to clear my mind about a behaviour of JPA when I keep in mind hibernate can have only one object reference for the managed entity

Comment: Just adding that if it does not apply with Hibernate it is not safe to assumption in JPA generally. So while it might work in - and note I do not say it works, never tested - OpenJPA and/or EclipseLink it still does not work in Hibernate.